# How to initial unpacked array with another unpacked array

Tags: arrays, queue, system-verilog

I have the following queue which I create in my sequence:

```
bit [31:0] transfers_seq [$];
```

I enter the following values to the queue:

```
{{00000000, 12345678, 54871245},{12454612, 00000000, 12367894}}
```

Now I have to pass the transfers_seq to another queue which in the transaction file by initial function that I wrote in the transaction file

transaction file:

```
class axi_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item();
   bit [31:0] transfers [$];

function init ( bit [31:0] transfers2init [$]);

endfunction: init
```

How can I assign the  "bit [31:0] transfers2init [$]" to the "bit [31:0] transfers [$]" in the init function?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign one queue to another:

```
transfers = transfers2init;
```

It will copy the elements of transfer2init to transfers. You can check it here:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3q3f

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return something and, to return a queue, you need a `typedef`:

```
typedef bit [31:0] queue [$];
```

Then, in your function, you can just copy one queue to the other (as suggested in another answer here):

```
function queue init ( queue transfers2init);
  init=transfers2init;
endfunction: init
```

But this is so simple, you don't really need a function.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3kyE

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign that.

```
transfer = transfer2init
```